# Reporting problems with multiple objects

Tags: reporting, custom-report-type, joined-reports, report-builder

Hello: I have what sounded like a very simple task to fulfill. Create a report of Accounts that includes a field showing the number of Cases associated with the account.

So the final report should resemble a list view, with some general account information, Account Name, Owner, Zip Code and a couple other standard fields. Then there should be a field with the number of Cases tied to the account.

I can get a sum next to an account name using Summary or Matrix reports. But when I add any additional account field it adds a second Summary line. The line serves no purpose and negates what I am trying to do, one line per account.

This seems like it should be extremely simple to accomplish, but I cannot figure it out despite working through the reporting Trailheads etc.

Can anyone shed some light on how I can do this?

Comment: This is not possible - you will be always getting another line if you add to the report more fields, different from what group field(s) are. As a workaround, you can save report with hidden details, and users would click on 'Show details' only when they want to see them.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to keep your report clean is to create a field on Account that stores the number of Cases on an Account. Since Account is a lookup relationship you can't use rollup summary fields here. So you would have to use apex for that (or workflow / processbuilder). An Apex example you find here on [developer.salesforce.com](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000DDBWIA4).

Answer (score 0):

You can use hid details as @Oleksiy mentioned, it would be a good Option to get the summary for both Number or Case and Summary for the other Field.

But what is that **second field**? Is it a **Picklist**? If so, we can use a **Matrix Report** where you can have two or upto four fields grouped together to form a Matrix Report.

The following links might help you more

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.fundamentals.meta/fundamentals/adg_reports_matrix_try_it_out.htm

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=reports_changing_format.htm&type=0